# Eliminating Initial keypress delay

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, awt

When you type into a textbox and hold a key, you get (a.......aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa), depending on the initial key press delay.

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // Handle key press here
    }
```

I'm creating a game in which the user's reflexes are very important. How can I eliminate this delay completely? The above code does not work. I have also tried overriding processKeyEvent with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These events are generated by the JVM / operating system, and unless you instruct the user to change the key-delay / key-repeat settings I'm afraid you'll have to do some more work.

I suggest you create a Timer which fires events in the correct rate, start and stop the timer upon `keyPressed` / `keyReleased`.

Comment: @David: Don't think so - I think aioobe is right, in that there isn't really much of a workaround, since it's all OS-based.

Comment: Be aware this approach only works on Windows as it generates multiple keyPressed events (as the key is held down) and only a single keyReleased event (when the key is released). However, I believe other OS will generate a keyPressed/keyReleased pair of events at the repeat rate frequency which defeats the purpose of using a Timer. I have not seen a good platform independent solution for this problem.